# Обновить данные за одну транзакцию

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть набор из **k** штук **id**, которые в базе выступают первичными ключами. Я знаю, что все эти **id** (первичные ключи) есть в БД. Я могу их обновлять за **k** транзакций так:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = new_val_1, col2 = new_val_2, col3 = new_val_3 WHERE id=id_i;
```

При этом, известно, что все обновляемые могут отличаться друг от друга.

Но это неэффективно. Подскажите, как сделать эту же операцию за **1** транзакцию?

Comment: А СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: @Viktorov postgres

Comment: Значения колонок для всех случаев должны стать одни и те же, или для каждой строки разные?

Comment: @Viktorov разные, конечно. В противном случае, задача тривиальная

Comment: а откуда берутся значения `id` и `new_val_1`, `new_val_2`, etc.?

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Comment: @MaxU считайте, что id -- это первичный ключ, new_val_i -- это значения, которые нужно поставить на место старых в соответствующие колонки. Эти значения заданы.

Comment: заданы где / в каком виде?

Comment: id -- название колонки (столбца), который является первичным ключом

Comment: Запрос != транзакция. Вы можете совершенно банальным способом обновить что угодно в транзакции, если обернёте любое число запросов в begin/commit.

Comment: @Мелкий т.е. можно обойтись без мёрджа, обернув всё в begin/commit?

Comment: По-моему, самым простым вариантом будет записать все новые значения и `id` во временную таблицу и проапдейтить оригинальную таблицу одним `UPDATE`

Comment: @Viktorov Спасибо, изучу

Comment: Позже напишу развёрнутый ответ, как сделаю задачу свою. P.s. Если это кто-нибудь сделает за меня, то отмечу, как правильный. Если возьмётесь это делать за меня, рассмотрите вариант с begin/commit и merge.

Comment: @MaxU не будет ли это слишком затратно?

Comment: С точки зрения производительности - это обычно более эффективно. Хотя с PostgreSQL я практически не работал, поэтому точно не уверен...

Comment: @Viktorov, вы нагугулили что-то немного не то. merge в postgresql нет. Патч для pg11 был влит и отменён в апреле. Возможно появится в pg12 https://commitfest.postgresql.org/18/1446/
Временная таблица - будет сильно плохо если её создавать 100/сек. Да и не нужна времянка когда CTE есть

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+bulk+update

Comment: @Мелкий что такое CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы спрашиваете про 1 транзакцию. Вы можете сделать практически что угодно и каким угодно числом запросов в одной транзакции.

```
begin;
-- практически любые запросы в нужном количестве
UPDATE table SET col1 = new_val_1, col2 = new_val_2, col3 = new_val_3 WHERE id=id_i
UPDATE table SET col1 = new_val_1, col2 = new_val_2, col3 = new_val_3 WHERE id=id_i
commit;
```

И это будет ответ на заданный вопрос. Это ровно одна транзакция с ровно одним fsync при записи WAL. К тому же с использованием prepared statements это часто хорошо выглядит в приложении и позволяет чуть сэкономить на парсере запроса.

Но обновить несколько строк одной таблички можно и другими способами.

### insert on conflict

В частности подойдёт для вашей задачи, хоть и был реализован для более общей upsert возможности: [`insert .. on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) появившийся в версии 9.5 реализует логику вставить или обновить строку если такая есть по уникальному ключу:

```
insert into table (id, col1, col2)
values (...),(...),...
on conflict (id) do update set col1 = excluded.col1, col2 = excluded.col2
```

Поскольку у вас заведомо id известны, поведение устраивает, insert заметит конфликт по id и будет обновлять эти строки как указано в on conflict. Ключевое слово `excluded` - ссылка на вставляемые данные соответствующей строки.

### Common Table Expressions

Либо универсальный способ сделать что-нибудь странное одним запросом - [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

```
with data (new_id, new_col1, new_col2) as (
    values(...),(...)
)
update table set
    col1 = new_col1,
    col2 = new_col2,
from data
where new_id = id;
```

### Temporary table

Так же упомянутый в комментариях способ и распространённый в других СУБД. Создать временную табличку, записать в неё нужные данные, затем одним или парой запросов обновить данные в целевой таблице. Как-то так:

```
create temporary table data (new_id int, new_col1 type, new_col2 type);
insert into data values (...), (...);
update table set
    col1 = new_col1,
    col2 = new_col2,
from data
where new_id = id;
```

Но зачем, если есть CTE? К тому же временные таблицы в postgresql сделаны таким способом, что часто (много в секунду) их создавать не стоит, это приведёт к проблемам с системным каталогом и замедлению работы всей базы.

### MERGE

Возможно знакомого по другим СУБД выражения MERGE в PstgreSQL пока ещё нет. Возможно появится в каком-нибудь следующем релизе, работы над ним [ведутся](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/18/1446/).

Comment: Можно, конечно, поугарать и назначить премию за вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE table SET col1 = new_val_1, col2 = new_val_2, col3 = new_val_3 WHERE id=id_i;

...

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Простите, не могу пока что отметить, как правильный, поскольку хочу сделать небольшой обзор по возможным способам решения этой задачи, которые обсуждались в комментах. Если сделаете такой обзор, то отмечу.